# Setting a default value to a field for which the schema already has a default value

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

let say we have following schema.

```
let aSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  x: {
    type: String,
    default: "A",
    enum: ["A", "B", "C"]
  }
});

let bSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  y: {
    type: aSchema
  } // need to set default value of y.x as "B" here.
});
```

how can I set the default values generated for the bSchema.y.x to "B" ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, aSchema has a default value of 'A', but you want a default value of 'B' for bSchema.y.

Looks to me like you'd need a different schema for that, with the default value of 'B'

Comment: I'm trying to reuse schema as nested ones for re-usability. If there's a feature as such it would greatly help.